# Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying

Tags: hyper-v, vagrant

when i try to create a VM using vagrant up it's output show like this. how can i resolve this? im using a existing vhdx(using manually created vhdx and also it conected to the domain). I use the password of the vhdx ex:- "config.winrm.username = "Administrator"" but it didn't work for me.

- how do i give username and password while creating the hyper-v vm(vagrant up)
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

it arise because i did not enable basic auth and allow unencrypted traffic on the .box file. The packer templates set this up at the end of the box preparation. so in this situation want to run this in the VM(VM that error occurs):

winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'